# Why heatmap.2 add unwanted replicate columns?

Tags: r, plot

Given this data, (complete one can be found here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=6NTcnLj7):

```
Probes  Gene.symbol ImmGen  FOO_YJ_06.ip    FOO_MI_06.ip    FOO_NL_06.id    FOO_YJ_06.id    FOO_MI_06.id    BAR_NN_06.ip    BAR_PR_06.ip    BAR_YJ_06.ip    BAR_MI_06.ip    BAR_NL_06.id    BAR_YJ_06.id    BAR_MI_06.id    BAR_NN_24.ip    BAR_PR_24.ip    BAR_YJ_24.ip    BAR_MI_24.ip    BAR_NN_06.ip    BAR_NN_24.ip    BAR_PR_06.ip    BAR_PR_24.ip    BAR_YJ_06.ip    BAR_YJ_24.ip    BAR_MI_06.ip    BAR_MI_24.ip    BAR_NL_06.id    BAR_YJ_06.id    BAR_MI_06.id    TXT_NL_06.id    TXT_YJ_06.ip    TXT_MI_06.ip    TXT_YJ_06.id    TXT_MI_06.id    XXX_YJ_06.ip    XXX_MI_06.ip    XXX_NL_06.id    XXX_YJ_06.id    XXX_MI_06.id    KTH_NL_06.id    KTH_YJ_06.ip    KTH_MI_06.ip    K3_YJ_06.id K3_MI_06.id UUU_YJ_06.in    UUU_MI_06.in    DAR_NL_06.id    DAR_YJ_06.id    DAR_MI_06.id
1425352_at  Rcor3   StromalCells(12.99),DendriticCells(12.18),StemCells(11.43),NKCells(10.50),Macrophages(10.11),abTcells(9.11),Neutrophils(8.72),Monocytes(8.63),Bcells(8.61),gdTCells(7.71)   1.162   0.795   0.695   0.701   1.085   1.052   1.544   0.75    1.305   1.213   1.142   0.814   0.79    0.89    1.691   1.013   1.052   0.79    1.544   0.89    0.75    1.691   1.305   1.013   1.213   1.142   0.814   1.556   0.744   1.22    1.239   1.164   0.827   1.203   0.778   0.929   0.95    0   0.877   0.906   1.294   0.904   0   1.2 0.927   0.704   1.181
1417466_at  Rgs5    StromalCells(72.03),Neutrophils(3.39),DendriticCells(3.31),NKCells(3.28),Monocytes(3.25),Macrophages(3.15),gdTCells(3.01),abTcells(2.99),Bcells(2.80),StemCells(2.80)   1.149   0.904   1.225   0.821   1.075   0.947   0.969   1.262   0.868   1.013   0.984   0.938   0.925   1.11    1.36    1.014   0.947   0.925   0.969   1.11    1.262   1.36    0.868   1.014   1.013   0.984   0.938   0.877   0.887   1.035   1.226   0.979   1.142   1.126   0.933   0.854   1.033   0.911   1.255   1.038   1.125   1.086   1.18    0.958   1.115   1.017   1.061
```

I obtain this heatmap, shown only by tail. Note that
it added the unwanted extra replicated columns (marked with red box).

For example `BAR_YJ_06.ip` only appear once in the data above. But in the plot it appear
twice `BAR_YJ_06.ip` and `BAR_YJ_06.ip.1`

Why is that? Hand how can I remove them?

[image]

This is the code I use to generate the above figure:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

library(gplots);
library(RColorBrewer);


plot_hclust  <- function(inputfile,clust.height,type.order=c(),row.margins=30) {

    dat.bcd <- read.table(inputfile,na.strings=NA, sep="\t",header=TRUE);
    base <- substr(basename(inputfile), 1, nchar(basename(inputfile)) - 4 )
    rownames(dat.bcd) <- do.call(paste,c(dat.bcd[c("Probes","Gene.symbol","ImmGen")],sep=" "))
    dat.bcd <- dat.bcd[,!names(dat.bcd) %in% c("Probes","Gene.symbol","ImmGen")] 
    dat.bcd <- dat.bcd

    # Clustering and distance function
    hclustfunc <- function(x) hclust(x, method="complete")
    distfunc <- function(x) dist(x,method="maximum")


    # Select based on FC, as long as any of them >= anylim

    anylim <- 2.0
    dat.bcd <- dat.bcd[ apply(dat.bcd, 1,function(x) any (x >= anylim)), ]
    nrow(dat.bcd);

    #print(heatout):


    # Clustering functions
    height <- clust.height; 

    # Define output file name
    heatout <- paste("myheatmap.pdf",sep="");

print(heatout)

    # Compute distance and clusteirn function
    d.bcd <- distfunc(dat.bcd)
    fit.bcd <- hclustfunc(d.bcd)


    # Plot the hierarchical dendogram without heatmap
    # Cluster by height
    #cutree and rect.huclust has to be used in tandem
    clusters <- cutree(fit.bcd, h=height) 
    nofclust.height <-  length(unique(as.vector(clusters)));

    myorder <- colnames(dat.bcd); 
    if (length(type.order)>0) {
     myorder <- type.order
    }

    # Define colors
    #hmcols <- rev(brewer.pal(11,"Spectral"));
    hmcols <- rev(redgreen(2750));
    selcol <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(12,"Set3"))
    selcol2 <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9,"Set1"))
    sdcol= selcol(5);
    clustcol.height = selcol2(nofclust.height);


    # Plot heatmap
  pdf(file=heatout,width=50,height=80); 


   par(xaxs="i");
   # We do bi-clustering 
   heatmap.2(as.matrix(dat.bcd), trace='none', dendrogram='both',Colv=T, scale='row', 
           hclust=hclustfunc, distfun=distfunc, col=hmcols,
           symbreak=T,
           margins=c(15,200), keysize=0.5,
           labRow=rownames(dat.bcd),
           lwid=c(2,0.1,4), lhei=c(0.05,3),
           lmat=rbind(c(5,0,4),c(3,1,2)),
           RowSideColors=clustcol.height[clusters])
    dev.off();

}

# Plotting 
plot_hclust("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=6NTcnLj7",clust.height=3);
```

Comment: This doesn't appear as a `heatmap.2` issue. All of those duplicated samples are present in your data, available via the pastebin link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a `heatmap.2` issue. All of those duplicated samples appear in your source data frame. You should review your workflow and fix the step at which the duplicates got introduced into the data.

Alternative *ad hoc* solution is to remove any duplicated columns from your data frame before plotting the heatmap:

```
data <- read.table(file='http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=6NTcnLj7', header=T)

# obtain the logical vector (TRUE/FALSE), where TRUE == duplicated elements
ind <- duplicated(t(data))

# retain only the unique columns
# ! == inverts the logical vector, so TRUE == unique elements
subset <- data[,!ind]
```